# Making 3 cells always sum to 1

Tags: excel, populate

I have three cells in excel. They must always sum to 1. When the user inputs into any two of the cells, e.g. 0.2 and 0.4, I want the third cell to automatically populate (with 0.4 in this example) so that the three cells together sum to 1.

Hope this is clear.
Thanks.

Comment: if you had formulas in the cells they would be overwritten when the user typed in a value so you will need to run some VBA in Worksheet_Change that figures out how to make it add up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For cells **A1**, **B1**, and **C1**  try this small event macro:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim RW As Range
    Set RW = Range("A1:C1")
    If Intersect(Target, RW) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(RW) <> 2 Then Exit Sub
    fillin = 1 - Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(RW)
    For Each r In RW
        If r.Value = "" Then
            Application.EnableEvents = False
                r.Value = fillin
            Application.EnableEvents = True
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the following solution. You can use different formulas with IF statements.

I uploaded an image here: http://postimg.org/image/e559dj55b/

![In the red section you have formulas which check if the value in cells 1,2,3 are "", if yes, then to get a sum of 1 you would need the remaining part which can be describen 1 minus the two other cells][1]

At the end only to get the numbers in one row you can get one of the above, red or green section, and set the cell to that value where there is not an empty space.

I hope that solve the problem for you!

PS: Sorry for the German above. Falsch means wrong!